# jquery $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() not triggering document.ready() for second time

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using jquery, backbonejs and underscorejs for my project. I want to upload image using ajaxForm and document.ready(). On productImageView.js I have

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/product/productImageTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, productImageTemplate) {
var ProductImageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.off();
    },
    render: function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
                alert("Image uploaded");
            });
        });
        this.$el.html(productImageTemplate);
    }
});
return ProductImageView;
});
```

On productImageTemplate.html is

```
<form id="myForm" action="upload_image.php" method="post"> 
<input name="uploadfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" id="uploadButton" value="Upload" />
```

For the first time I upload the image, everything is ok. But when the second time I visit the page and upload, the `document.ready()` not working.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Resource: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `this.$el.html(productImageTemplate);` before `ajaxForm`.

You do not need `$(function() {` here. When you render a view DOM should be already ready. If you are not sure about that - place your scripts right before `</body>`.

Comment: Voila !! Thanks for saving my life. May god bless you.

Answer (score 0):

try this for the ajax in the render:

```
$('#uploadButton').click(function(){
    $.post('process_file.php', $('#myForm').serialize());
});
```